# Controlled Transaction Blocking - Resume Behavior

Tags: sql-server, locking, blocking

When several procedures are blocked on a shared resource, how does sql server pick which one to resume?

#### Example 1

```
proc sp_a
begin tran

  select 1 from dbo.lock_tbl with ( tbllockx )
  
  delay wait for '00:00:01' 
  commit / rollback;
```

Execute

```
exec sp_a -- on terminal 1
exec sp_a -- on terminal 2
exec sp_a -- on terminal 3
```

Does sql server choose whether to start the instance on 2 or 3 first?

#### Example 2

Closer to intended use

```
proc sp_b @source_param

declare @rows cursor = ... get_rows( @source_param ) 
while ( ... for each @row )
begin
  begin tran  
    select 1 from dbo.lock_tbl with ( tbllockx )

    -- do logic
    exec sp_g @row

  commit / rollback;

  delay wait for '00:00:01' 
end
```

Execute

```
exec sp_b 'd' -- on terminal 1
exec sp_b 'e' -- on terminal 2
exec sp_b 'f' -- on terminal 3
```

Will the code above round-robin execute procedure sp_g from each procedure
eg: will it execute sp_g on terminal 1, then execute sp_g on terminal 2, then execute sp_g on terminal 3, then execute g on terminal 1, etc?

Followups :

Does it pass the lock to the procedure which has been waiting the longest?

Is there a way to encourage round robin behavior?

#### Rationale

( optional )
The database is a low transaction database, but will hit deadlocks when multiple transactions occur at the same time, due to complex execution business logic. A global lock table can be used to eliminate deadlocks via throttling the execution flow to one thread at a time. Keeping the execution synchronous seems more desirable than restructuring the database and UI into asynchronous queues. The work will take place in small transactions and hand off procedure control between the procedures, which will take turns to complete their respective work in chunks, thus slowing the completion of the tasks in exchange for reliable synchronous completion.

Comment: Consider using Application Locks instead of a lock table.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017  Among the benefits are that Application Locks can be released before the end of a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1: You shouldn't care. The process is much more involved than it seems, and I don't think you have any guarantee. The 3 commands go into the queue in order. The first one is pulled and executed, when the second is attempted, the engine may choose to put it back in queue if it waits for more than some threshold, and the third may be pulled and attempted. if it happens that the resources are now free, the 3rd will be executed first. if not, it may go back in queue again.

Example 2: I think the above explains it, and the answer to both your questions is no AFAIK, unless you develop an execution buffer of your own. Don't.

Rationale: Now you got to the core challenge, which should really have been the title - "How to deal with deadlocks". You assumed that your 'global lock table' solution is the only way to make things right, but I think the price of losing all concurrency is not worth it. It would be easier just to have the procedures executed serially using a scheduler of some sort. You will open a Pandora box with this approach that will be hard to close. Queuing and syncing is a very complicated challenge.

If I were in your place, I would first investigate the root cause of the deadlocks. Sometimes, something as simple as adding or modifying an index can solve it.
If you [post your deadlock graphs](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/) here, along with the involved queries with their execution plans, people will help you pin point the root issue.

HTH